# Could Isaiah 6:1-2 be an allusion to Exodus 33:20?

Tags: exodus, isaiah

Exodus 33:20 (NKJV)

> 20 But He said, **“You cannot see My face;** for no man shall  see Me, and live.”

Isaiah 6:1-2 (NKJV)

> 1 In the year that King Uzziah died, I saw the Lord sitting on a throne,  high and lifted up, and the train of His robe filled the temple.  2 Above it  stood seraphim; each one had six wings: **with two he covered his face,**  with two he covered his feet, and with two he flew.

In Exodus God made it very clear that no man can look at the brightness of his glory & live,so could the Seraphim have covered their faces because of the glory of his presence

Comment: This may be assuming the purpose for why the seraphim cover their faces that the text doesn't directly indicate. Perhaps that's something an answer will need to address?

Comment: See also Daniel 10:5-9.

Answer (score 5):

"[Allusion](https://www.academia.edu/840940/Inner-Biblical_Allusion)" is certainly the wrong word for whatever relation these two texts have.

For there to be an "allusion", the text must include some kind of verbal association whereby the connection between the texts can be triggered in the mind of the reader/hearer. And that is simply lacking in the case of the two texts brought together by OP.

There may, on the other hand, be some shared conceptual space in terms of thinking about "God's face" in the Hebrew Bible (see the [many hits a search of Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22exodus+33%22+%22god%27s+face%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39) gives for `"god's face" + "exodus 33"`, for example). But even that consideration fails to draw these two particular texts together in any significant way.

Comment: @David, yes agreed but this is an indirect reference, not explicitly mentioned,but why would they have covered their faces in the presence of God other than avoiding looking at his glory

Comment: @collenndhlovu "Indirect reference" is not a meaningful category of "allusion". The OBVIOUS reason the seraphim cover their faces in Isaiah 6 is because the One on the throne is "Holy, Holy, Holy". They didn't need to read Exod 33:20.

Comment: @David Give a biblical citation where it points to them covering their faces because of the One on the throne is Holy,Holy,Holy

Comment: @collenndhlovu [Isaiah 6:2-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+6%3A2-3&version=NIV).