# Is Ezekiel 28:22-24 an allusion to 1 kings 16:29-31?

Tags: ezekiel, 1-kings

(KJV)Ezekiel 28:22-24

> And say, Thus saith the Lord God ; Behold, I am against thee, **O Zidon**; and I will be glorified in the midst of thee: and they shall know that I am the Lord , when I shall have executed judgments in her, and shall be sanctified in her. [23] For I will send into her pestilence, and blood into her streets; and the wounded shall be judged in the midst of her by the sword upon her on every side; and they shall know that I am the Lord . [24] ***And there shall be no more a pricking brier*** unto the house of Israel, nor any grieving thorn of all that are round about them, that despised them; and they shall know that I am the Lord God

(KJV)1 Kings 16:29-31

> And in the thirty and eighth year of Asa king of Judah began Ahab the son of Omri to reign over Israel: and Ahab the son of Omri reigned over Israel in Samaria twenty and two years. [30] And Ahab the son of Omri did evil in the sight of the Lord above all that were before him. [31] And it came to pass, as if it had been a light thing for him to walk in the sins of Jeroboam the son of Nebat, that he took to wife Jezebel the daughter of Ethbaal king of the **Zidonians**, and went and served Baal, and worshipped him.

The prophet Ezekiel takes a proclamation against Sidon that ***there shall be no more pricking brier***-nothing to excite Israel to idolatry when restored from their captivity, could the prophet be referring to Jezebel daughter of Ethabaal king of Sidonians & wife to Ahab king of Israel who was the greatest curse to Israel & universal restorer of idolatry in the land

.

Comment: (1) It would help if you used a more modern translation: there are plenty, and the sense would be more clear to you. (2) Did you read the article linked in [an answer](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/25902/2215) to one of your previous questions? That should have helped here, too.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The passage in [Ezekiel 28:20-26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel+28%3A20-26&version=NIV;WLC) works this way:

1. 28:20-23 Oracle against Sidon
2. 28:24-26 Israel Secure

   1. 28:24 Safe from surrounding people
   2. 28:25-26 Gathered by God in security

Note these structural features:

- the distinctive (in Ezekiel) concluding "recognition" formula, "then they/you will know that I am the Lord" in vv. 23, 24, and 26;
- the repetition of "their neighbours" (*sebibotam*) in vv. 24 and 26;
- vv. 24-26 come "precisely at the halfway point in the collection of foreign-nation oracles. Verses 24 and 26 make explicit what is sometimes implicit and often simply absent from foreign oracles: the subduing of God’s enemies will result in the well-being of God’s own people." (ESV Study Bible)

So OP's concern with v. 24 participating in an "allusion" to 1 Kings 16:29-31 is doubly mis-placed:

- v. 24 is *not* part of the oracle against Sidon (and it explicitly speaks of Israel's neighbours *inclusively*, and is so not speaking of Sidon particularly); and
- there is nothing in these verses to connect them to 1 Kings 16 beyond the bare mention of Sidon, which is nothing special (occurs > 30x in Hebrew Bible).

So there is nothing to link Ezekiel's oracle against Sidon to 1 Kings 16, certainly nothing that merits the term "[allusion](https://www.academia.edu/840940/Inner-Biblical_Allusion)".

Comment: Why separate v.24 from 22 & 23 when the judgments against Sidon result in the security of Israel from all around inc

Comment: Verse 24 begins with a conjunction (and) which means its linked to the previous verses  then why separate v.24 from 22 & 23 when  the judgments executed in 22 & 23 result in security for Israel from all around including Sidon

Comment: (1) Why separate? Because (a) the concluding formula, and (b) the explicit reference to "neighbours" shows v. 24 *is not about Sidon*.

Comment: (2) The conj. which starts v. 24 is meaningless for this discussion. Note [how often it is simply omitted](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Ezekiel%2028:24) by modern (and non-wooden!) translations. Note, too, that the **books** of Lev, Num, Josh, Jdg, Ruth, 1-2 Sam, 1-2 Kgs, 2 Chron, Ezra, Esther, and Ezekiel *all* begin with "and". The conjunction in Hebrew does not mean what you think it means here.

Comment: no more. . . brier. . . unto. . . Israel--as the idolatrous nations left in Canaan (among which Zidon is expressly specified in the limits of Asher, Jdg 1:31 ) had been ( Num 33:55 Jos 23:13 ). "A brier," first ensnaring the Israelites in sin, and then being made the instrument of punishing them.

Comment: Prophecy against Zidon. Zidon (mod. Saida) was more ancient than Tyre and was the original metropolis of Phoenicia Gen 10:19, but in the times of Phoenician greatness it ever played a subordinate part. Only once Jdg 10:12 do we find the "Zidonians" in conflict with Israel. The evil which they did was the seducing them to idolatry (compare Eze 28:24), as in the case of Jezebel, daughter of Ethbaal, king of the Zidonians Kg1 16:31.

Comment: But Collen -- *none* of that makes Ezek 28:24ff. an *allusion* to 1 Kgs 16:29ff. Please read the article I linked (again!). (And Ezek 28:24 **is not about Sidon**!)