# Why do the Seraphim in Isaiah 6:2 cover their feet?

Tags: isaiah, angels

In Isaiah 6:2, the Seraphim in the presence of God have six wings.

> Isaiah 6:2 Seraphs stood over him; each one had six wings. With two wings they covered their faces, with two they covered their feet, and they used the remaining two to fly. ([NET](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Isaiah+6:2))

The reason for the pair to fly is obvious. The two covering the face are because they are [in the presence of God who is "Holy, holy, holy."](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/25902/363)

However, why are the feet covered? What is the significance of the wings covering the feet?

Comment: Two possibilities I can think of: (1) feet are dirty, and therefore unclean (cf. Moses, Joshua told to remove their shoes), or (2) 'feet' is here a euphemism as sometimes elsewhere in the bible, and hence 'it' needs covering.

Comment: A bird's wings stem from the middle of its back side. For obvious technical reasons, they cannot be folded so as to cover both the upper (*face*) and lower (*feet*) sides of its body *simultaneously*.

Comment: @MarkEdward, writing that up with a few cross references would qualify as an upvotable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seraphim convey a different concept to cherubim ('the living' which appear in Eden, on the *kapporeth* of the ark, in the oracle of the temple and in Ezekiel; and whose name appears again, borne by the man Kerub, who came back from captivity).

*Saraph* [8314] the Hebrew word behind the English translation, occurs seven times in the [Piel](http://www.dabar.org/Tools/Heb-Piel-Pual.html), the active and intensive form, and once more, making eight, as a man's name.

*Serephah* [8316] occurs thirteen times and is translated by the KJV and by Young as *burn* or *burning*, but not a normal burning; it is evident from the occurrences, and the link in one place to brimstone, that it is an intense burning.

Together, there are twenty-one references, a significant number in scripture.

---

The same word as appears here, *seraphim*, is elsewhere translated *fiery serpent* [KJV] but in those other places they are not directly related to the throne of God. Here they are.

It is clear that, here, *saraph*, corporately, represent a concept. The literal translation [Young's Literal] reads :

> Seraphs are standing above it: six wings hath each one; with two covering its face, and with two covereth its feet, and with two flieth.

The very wording blends the imagery from plural to singular; and we are not told, in any case - in this place - how many there are.

Two wings cover the face, two cover the feet. The mode of progress is obscured and the identity is obscured and their sight is obscured. And what does the obscuring - is something heavenly; the wing. The wing is a means of heavenly motion. *And here, that which propels in a heavenly manner, is the very thing that obscures.*

These things are mysteries; they require revelation; and he to whom it is revealed is he who shall interpret. But interpratation is off-topic, here, so that is all I shall say.

---

*Saraph* : Num 21:6, Num 21:8, Deu 8:15, Isa 6:2, Isa 6:6, Isa 14:29, Isa 30:6

*Saraph*, the man : I Chron 4:22

[The Piel Form](http://www.dabar.org/Tools/Heb-Piel-Pual.html)

Comment: This is interesting conjecture but it does not answer the question

Comment: @DavidD _The mode of progress is obscured and the identity is obscured and their sight is obscured. And what does the obscuring - is something heavenly; the wing. The wing is a means of heavenly motion. And here, that which propels in a heavenly manner, is the very thing that obscures._ : is my answer to the question. It is at least a better answer than the one you chose not to supply.

Comment: Nigel J - I apologize for offending you.

Comment: @DavidD None taken. But I cannot but help remember the words of J N Darby : _I prefer my way of doing things to your way of not doing them._ Too many are content to sit in the 'scorner's chair', casting critical comment, being 'armchair critics'. See Psalm 1:1. Achieve first ; only then - comment on the achievement of others.

Answer (score 0):

Two wings over the eyes represents reverence,  Two wings over the feet represents humility, and the Two wings they used to fly shows they where in action. To be in service for All Mighty God you must meet these requirements. "Influence"by William Branham preached on Feb.15 1964 staring at paragraph 84.May God Richly Bless You.

Comment: How do you know that is what they symbolise?

Answer (score -3):

Scriptural Hebrew includes many euphemisms. The "feet" here are actually sex organs.

The CEV and GNT English translations hint at the real Hebrew meaning by saying their "bodies/body" respectively.

Tripp Hudgins' chapter "Of Feet and Angelic Netherbits" in the devotional *Disquiet Time* shares a debate he and his fellow Old Testament literature students had about why they covered their feet. He relates that the professor finally said, " 'Feet' is a euphemism for genitalia."

Dr. Michael S. Heiser on p. 81 of *Reversing Hermon*

> The Hebrew word translated "feet" (*regel*) is a well-known euphemism for genitalia in the Hebrew Bible (e.g. to "cover one's feet," meaning relieve oneself: Judges 3:24; 1 Samuel 24:4). By uncovering Boaz's "feet" (genitalia), Ruth is, in effect offering herself as a wife to Boaz. ... While the text provides no evidence of a sexual encounter between the two, what Ruth did would have an illicit feel to "proper" Israelites and later Jewish readers.

Comment: Sometimes feet are just feet. Please [edit] this to add supporting evidence for your conclusion.